# Add a column stating whether a record occurred across datasets

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have 2 dfs upon which I want to contact together and remove duplicates, but not before adding a column stating whether a record from df_b which will be dropped as a consequence of deduplication can state whether it occurred or not across both dfs, otherwise the column will remain blank stating that there was no occurrence for that record in df_b (not a duplicate across dfs).

Desired result `df_combined`

```
df_a

    title             director
0   Toy Story         John Lasseter
1   Goodfellas        Martin Scorsese
2   Meet the Fockers  Jay Roach
3   The Departed      Martin Scorsese

df_b

    title             director
0   Toy Story         John Lass
1   The Hangover      Todd Phillips
2   Rocky             John Avildsen
3   The Departed      Martin Scorsese


df_combine =  pd.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df_combined

title                 director.         occurence_both
0   Toy Story         John Lasseter     b
1   Goodfellas        Martin Scorsese
2   Meet the Fockers  Jay Roach      
3   The Departed      Martin Scorsese   b
5   The Hangover      Todd Phillips
6   Rocky             John Avildsen
```

Comment: Does `df_b` actually have "John Lass", if so, what are the rules for associating partial matches?

Comment: @HenryEcker yes I put that in deliberately as I'm just concerned with the title when checking for duplicates across the datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` to mark all duplicates and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to convert from boolean series to 'b' and ''. Then followup with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicate rows. Both operations should be subset to only the `title` column:

```
df_combine = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
# Mark Duplicates
df_combine['occurence_both'] = np.where(
    df_combine.duplicated(subset='title', keep=False), 'b', ''
)
# Drop Duplicates
df_combine = df_combine.drop_duplicates(subset='title')
```

`df_combine`:

```
              title         director occurence_both
0         Toy Story    John Lasseter              b
1        Goodfellas  Martin Scorsese               
2  Meet the Fockers        Jay Roach               
3      The Departed  Martin Scorsese              b
5      The Hangover    Todd Phillips               
6             Rocky    John Avildsen
```

Comment: Great, this works perfectly for my use-case. Out of interest is this the best way to approach this via concat or could a better way be done via merge?

Comment: You can merge with indicator. The problem is that if you have multiple columns reducing them down will be tricky. Take a look at `df_a.merge(df_b, on='title', how='outer', indicator='occurrence_both')` notice that you end up with a `director_x` and `director_y` column. Reducing that to one column is not too hard, but if you had 100s of columns it could be a lot to manage.